# Ubuntu BackInTime: .dbus Permissions denied for backup

Tags: ubuntu, backup

I use BackInTime to do backups in Ubuntu 18.04. All snapshots return the error message

```
Error: rsync: opendir "/home/userName/.dbus" failed: Permission denied (13)
```

Can I set .dbus to `755` or something? Will this affect the system?

Comment: I don't think you want to "willy nilly" change permissions, as this is opening up what are normally secure files, to less secure settings.  I think a better approach would be to use some sort of user/group settings, but I don't know.... currently also seeking an answer

Comment: the file you have in question is in your home directory, so I think it would be safe to update permissions.  But not for files outside your home directory, like in `/var` or `/etc`

Comment: Sounds related to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/502837/dbus-folder-in-home-folder-belongs-root - The answer says that directory should belong to you, and you can even delete it, and it should be recreated.

Answer (score 2):

Expounding on @Hans 's comment:

The `.dbus` directory just stores temporary information related to the current login session - it's essentially a cache, from a backup perspective.  To remove the error, you have three options:

1. Remove the directory, and it will be recreated with the correct permissions upon your next login.
2. Take ownership of the directory with `sudo chown -R username:username .dbus` (replace `username` with your username).
3. **Recommended:** Just tell your backup software to ignore the directory.  `.dbus` a cache, restoring it from a backup is totally unnecessary and pointless.  While you're at it, you can also safely ignore `.cache` and `.gvfs` (don't remove these two directories, just ignore them).  They are also cache directories.

Comment: So i can not backup for example /etc directory contents as user since it has root:root ownership? I have to somehow trigger backintime on background as root?